# Why doesn't my projectile game object move?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, topdown

I already tried numerous other solutions but none of them worked for me.
My projectiles just stand there even though I use `AddForce`.

Here's the code

```
public Transform gunExitPoint;
public int ProjectileVelocity;
public GameObject projectilePref;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        GameObject shot = Instantiate(projectilePref, gunExitPoint.position, gunExitPoint.rotation);

        Rigidbody2D rb = shot.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * ProjectileVelocity * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ProjectileVelocity` set to?

Comment: I assigned it in the editor, is it wrong?

Comment: If you debug your program and either set a break point on the `rb.AddForce()` call and/or a watch on `ProjectileVelocity` can you see that it is anything other than `0`?

Comment: how do i set a break point?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: i did it, but it was set at 10.

Comment: If you pull the calculation out of the function call to assign it to a variable, what is the result of that calculation? `float thrust = transform.forward * ProjectileVelocity * Time.deltaTime;` then `rb.AddForce(thrust, ForceMode2D.Impulse);`

Comment: okay first i had to change float to Vector, and then when i checked thrust's value was 0 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just going by what you have here, and assuming it is a complete example, your `int` variable `ProjectileVelocity` is unassigned. An unassigned `integer` type defaults to `0`. Multiplying by `0` results in a `0` value. If you use that as your force, then your projectile will not be going anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

after changing my code and using debugging (thanks gmiley) i was able to add the force to my projectiles, then i changed the rigidbody2d to dynamic and ramped up the velocity to 1000f. here is the code (it's a bit sloppy unfortunately)

```
public Vector2 thrust;
public Transform gunExitPoint;
public int ProjectileVelocity = 1000;
public GameObject projectilePref;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}


void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {

        GameObject shot = Instantiate(projectilePref, gunExitPoint.position, gunExitPoint.rotation);

        Rigidbody2D rb = shot.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        thrust = transform.up * ProjectileVelocity ;
        rb.AddForce(thrust, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```